# Can the Cow King's Set only drop in the Secret Cow Level?

Tags: diablo-ii

I'm looking to find my first Cow King's Set Item yet. According to [Silospen Drop Calculator](http://dropcalc.silospen.com) the set pieces can drop pretty much anywhere. I have already dropped super rare items like f.e. 'Griffon's Eye', 'Immortal King's Soul Cage' or 'Crown of Ages', but haven't found a single set piece from the Cow King's. I pretty much never farm the Secret Cow Level. So my question is: can you drop the Cow King's set only in the Secret Cow Level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it can only drop in the Secret Cow Level.

[Multiple](https://www.diabloii.net/forums/threads/cow-king-set.704152/) [sources](https://diablo.fandom.com/wiki/Cow_King%27s_Leathers) [confirm](https://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Cow_King%27s_Leathers) this:

> This is a set of items which can only be found in the Secret Cow Level.

Comment: [Another source](https://diablo.gamepedia.com/Cow_King%27s_Leathers_(Diablo_II)).